# Как сдвинуть форму подписки вниз под фото?

Tags: html, css, форма

Здравствуйте. У меня на странице форма подписки устанавливается поверх фотографии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как её сдвинуть вниз под фото?

Comment: Пример нужен. http://jsfiddle.net здесь сделайте пробную страницу.

Comment: Сейчас, я схожу за картами, погадаю что там у вас и объясню..минуту

Comment: Ссылка на страницу : http://www.vivasan.me/partner/samgul/ А сервисом fiddle  я не пользовалась и разбираться там долго, наверное, времени нет. Спасибо всем, кто подскажет , как исправить ошибку.

Comment: @samgul , Оооо!  
Так за такие услуги деньги платить надо. Здесь такие вопросы не задают! Выложите маленький кусок кода и покажите что именно не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вам и накодили - черт ногу сломит))). Попап окно у вас скриптом позиционируется.

В коде страницы html найдите строки 310 и 311:

```
e.style.left = (ww - ew) / 2 + d.body.scrollLeft + (i * 10);    
e.style.top = (wh - eh) / 2 + d.body.scrollTop + (i * 10);
```

И полностью замените их на:

```
e.style.left = 400;    
e.style.top = 500;
```

Так вроде нормально получается.

Comment: так есть же решение. зачем вопрос закрывать??